# All row data is not getting reflected in Power BI from Marklogic

Tags: powerbi, marklogic, marklogic-10

I have a csv file with 3 rows of data which is stored in Marklogic and available in collections.
I am trying to access the content of the csv file from Power BI.
But from Power BI I can only access 1 row of data at one time whereas requirement is to see all rows of data.

Here are the details of the process I followed to achieve the functionality:

1. Used Marklogic ODBC driver(64bit) to connect Marklogic SQL from Power BI
2. Created template(used xquery) to implement the table structure in Marklogic
3. Used mlcp to import the csv file in the marklogic database.

Here is the template I used:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

if (xdmp:database-name(xdmp:database()) = "Documents")  then        
    let $shipment-CBE:=
    <template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
     <context>/shipment</context>
       <collections>
         <collections-and>
           <collection>PowerBI</collection>
           <collection>Shipment</collection>
         </collections-and>
       </collections>
       <rows>
         <row>
           <schema-name>Shipment</schema-name>
           <view-name>CBE2</view-name>
           <columns>
             <column>
               <name>DocType</name>
               <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
               <val>DocType</val>
             </column>
             <column>
               <name>User</name>
               <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
               <val>User</val>
            </column>
            <column>
          <name>ShipmentRef</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>ShipmentRef</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>Transmode</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>Trans_mode</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>Packagetype</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>Package_type</val>
        </column>
        <column>
          <name>Customer_Party_Name</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>Customer_Party_Name</val>
        </column>
       </columns>
    </row>
      </rows>
    </template>

    return ( 
      tde:template-insert("/powerbi/shipment-CBE2.xml",$shipment-CBE),
      "shipment-CBE.xml OK"
    )
else ("Please select the 'Documents' database.")
```

Here is the import command(saved as shipment.txt) used to import the csv file:

```
IMPORT
-input_file_path
../data/Shipment-CBE.csv
-input_file_type
delimited_text
-delimited_root_name
shipment
-username
admin
-password
*****
-host
owc-db01.owc.com
-port
8000
-output_uri_prefix
/powerbi/shipment/
-output_collections
PowerBI,Shipment
-uri_id
"DocType"
```

Running this MLCP command to execute the import command -

`mlcp.bat -options_file shipment.txt`

Comment: So, all data is inserted into the MarkLogic database correctly, but you aren't able to select all rows via PowerBI? You have provided how you have put the data into MarkLogic, but nothing describing how you are attempting to select and retrieve via PowerBI. When you say that you can select one at a time through PowerBI, how are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks for your response. One row at a time is getting inserted in the Marklogic itself whereas I want all the rows to get inserted whatever is available in the file. 
From Power BI , I am doing - Get Data->Others->ODBC->MarklogicSql->Then I can see the schemas inside the Marklogic Sql

Comment: So, how many documents are inserted into the database? And what do they look like (can you post an example)? Do you have 3 docs that have `/shipment` element?

Comment: In the Database, there are 1 document which is getting inserted. The document is in form of a xml file and it looks like this - 
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shipment>
  <DocType>Shipment</DocType>
  <User>c_saunders</User>
  <ShipmentRef>CBE00030965N</ShipmentRef>
  <Trans_mode>Road</Trans_mode>
  <Package_type>Cartons</Package_type>
  <Customer_Party_Name>MI Hub Limiteds</Customer_Party_Name>
</shipment>
```

Comment: And the csv file looks like this - 

```DocType,User,ShipmentRef,Trans_mode,Package_type,Customer_Party_Name
Shipment,j_henderson,CBE00030965N,Road,Cartons,MI Hub Limited
Shipment,a_gatfield,CBE00030965N,Road,Cartons,MI Hub Limiteds
Shipment,c_saunders,CBE00030965N,Road,Cartons,MI Hub Limited
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that you are importing each of the 3 CSV rows and inserting with the same URI of `/powerbi/shipment/Shipment`

This is because you have configured the `-uri_id` to be the "DocType" column, and each of your rows have the same value: `Shipment`.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_65814

> Optionally, override the default document URI by setting `-uri_id` to the name of the element from which to derive the document URI.

You could instead configure it to use the `User` column, so that the docs would be inserted with unique URIs:

- /powerbi/shipment/j_henderson
- /powerbi/shipment/c_saunders
- /powerbi/shipment/a_gatfield

Comment: Excellent. It worked fine as you suggested. Thanks for your help !!